# Is it possible to have a debt in real money cfd account?

Tags: trading, cfd

Is it possible to switch from a demo to a real money account in plus 500 and then try to trade with the $25 you start with? I'd like to try trading, starting only with this money, but I fear I could contract a debt if my position decreases so much that it ends in negative territory. To be more specific, I need to be sure that if i lose the $25 I end the game and there's no possibility to have any kind of debt.

Answer (score 1):

If you start trading in a real CFD account with only $25 and place a long trade with no stop loss on it and watch it go down in price, yes you will end up losing more than what is in your account and would have to make up the difference.

This $25 is not very much to start trading with, if you traded share CFDs then you would need to consider the commission in and out of the trade. You haven't mentioned which country you are in, but I am in Australia and the cheapest CFD Broker here charges minimum $5 commission in and $5 out of a trade. That means you would only have $15 worth left for your actual trade. You would need to take a very small position (even on margin), and then place a very tight stop loss (which might get gapped if you trade a very volatile stock, in which case you would still lose more that the $25).

If you are trading index or FX CFDs you might get away with not paying commissions but would still need to place a very tight stop on a very small position.

Your best bet would be to continue using the demo account while you learn more about trading in general and learn more about trading with CFDs. You should start with developing a trading plan and then some trading strategies. You can then practice and test your strategies on your demo account. In your trading plan don't forget to incorporate your risk management and position sizing.

Once you have learned all this and developed your trading plan and trading strategies you might want to start real trading with a bit more than the $25.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm from Italy. I'm curious about all this thing but the fact that i could lose more than the money I have in my account make me fear to lose my money.Anyway: they should have a payment method which they could take my money from...!?!?

Comment: Usually if your trade is looking like it will be too big for the amount you have in your account the broker will not let you take the trade in the first place. You have fear because you are trying to do something you know very little about. That is why learning about it first will take most of that fear away. In trading you need to not be afraid to take the occasional loss, in fact you should keep your losses small and let your winners run. Try reading the book "Trade your way to Financial Freedom" by Van Tharp.

Comment: Thank you again, I hope I could make my way through this and start trading a little bit!

Comment: After a while in which I leave the idea of trading I'm again here for some info. I'd like a confront about your answer, I visited the FAQ's site from my trader, and I found the issue I was asking here, the link is: [link](http://www.plus500.com/FAQ/Trading/CanBeInDebtToYou) . I want to know what do you think about it because it seems to me that the answer in the site contradicts your previous answer... thank you!

Comment: @AlessandroSassi - yes the margin call is there to try to prevent you from going into negative territory, but if you plan to start actual trading with only $25 then this will likely happen straight away. You might even need a minimum balance in your account before you can make a trade to reduce this from happening. You should look up maintenance margin in the website you linked.